# How to set zsh as default shell in openvz container?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, openvz, proxmox

I'm running a vz container (debian) on PVE, and I'd like to use zsh as my default shell when i run :

```
vzctl enter MY_CONTAINER_ID
```

I tried to run `chsh` in the container but it as no effect, unless I run `su root`, i'm still using bash.

Is-it at least possible ?

Anyone has succesfully achieved this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post on the openvz ask the same question and the reply indicate that /bin/bash is hardcoded in the code of vzctl.

Answer (score 3):

When there is a will, there is a way !

I replaced the whole content of `~/.bashrc` with :

```
zsh && exit
```

And it did the job... Maybe it's a bit hacky, but found no other way...